# Flatten outermost parenthesis

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

If I have the following data:

```
   data = {{-7.10543*10^-15, 3.29215}, {-7.10543*10^-15, 
        2.94365}, {-9.03439, 2.4954}, {-8.8538, 3.33308}, {-10.0876, 
        3.1443}, {-2.49194, 2.00957}, {-2.98661, 
        3.35066}, {-6.39488*10^-14, 3.29215}, {2.84217*10^-14, 
        2.73316}, {8.67852, 2.05735}, {2.85633, 3.04537}, {11.1115, 
        2.49008}, {2.74509, 3.11135}, {13.5305, 2.20002}};
```

How can I remove the outsides parenthesis with a command as to get:

```
{-7.10543`*^-15, -7.10543`*^-15, -9.03439`, -8.8538`, -10.0876`,-2.49194`, -2.98661`, -6.39488`*^-14, 2.8421699999999997`*^-14,8.67852`, 2.85633`, 11.1115`, 2.74509`, 13.5305`}, {3.29215`,2.94365`, 2.4954`, 3.33308`, 3.1443`, 2.00957`, 3.35066`, 3.29215`, 2.73316`, 2.05735`, 3.04537`, 2.49008`, 3.11135`, 2.20002`}?
```

Using `Flatten[data]` does not work

Comment: `Thread[data]` or `Transpose[data]`

Comment: I think you may be looking for `Transpose[data]`, or possibly `data[[All, 1]]` and `data[[All, 2]]`.  If the first possibility, then `Flatten[data, {{2}}]` will also work (even if the list is 'ragged')

Comment: Your stated desired output has a syntactically incorrect form, `{...}, {...}`. Others are implicitly suggesting the form should be `{{...}, {...}}`.  In short, you can restructure the data, but you can't remove the outside parentheses (except to obtain the undesired form returned by `Flatten[data]`).

Comment: Flatten 's fourth syntax

Comment: @John:  Please post the *minimal* problem.  You'll get more help.  Do you really need numbers such as -7.10543*-15?  Of course not. The whole problem could use instead:  `{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}`.  See?

Comment: The **key** question is what are you  going to do with `{a,b,c,...},{d,e,f,...}` **next**? Until we know **that**, we can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emphasize @MichaelE2's point in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245594/flatten-outermost-parenthesis#comment618111_245594) -- the output form you have specified is impossible, i.e., it is not a correctly-formed expression in the Wolfram language. There is *no* evaluation within the system that will produce that expression as an output.

As a simple example, try copying your intended result,

```
{-7.10543`*^-15, -7.10543`*^-15, -9.03439`, -8.8538`, -10.0876`,-2.49194`, -2.98661`, 
 -6.39488`*^-14, 2.8421699999999997`*^-14,8.67852`, 2.85633`, 11.1115`, 2.74509`, 
  13.5305`}, {3.29215`,2.94365`, 2.4954`, 3.33308`, 3.1443`, 2.00957`, 3.35066`, 3.29215`, 
  2.73316`, 2.05735`, 3.04537`, 2.49008`, 3.11135`, 2.20002`}
```

into a fresh cell, and evaluate it. If the expression were correctly formatted, the system would just return it untouched, but instead the system will just show a syntax error on the right-hand side.

> [image]

The reason this doesn't work is that you have two lists separated by a comma, i.e. `{...},{...}`, and that comma is acting as a separator between two parts of an expression (or a list) but that expression does not have a container (in technical terms, it doesn't have a head).  The natural head for this would be another list, in which case the correct syntax for what you want to express is not `{...},{...}` but `{{...},{...}}`.

As others have mentioned, if what you want is an output of the form `{{...},{...}}`, then the correct transformation is `Transpose[data]`.

Alternatively, if you just want the two sections to be produced independently, i.e. `{...}` and `{...}` as *separate* outputs, then you can just use a [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) specification for all of the 1st and all of the 2nd elements, giving you

```
data[[All, 1]]
data[[All, 2]]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data` is $n\times2$-dimension:

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
Flatten@Transpose@data
(* or *)
Flatten[Transpose[data]]
(* {a, c, e, b, d, f} *)
```

as well as

```
Flatten[{First /@ data, Last /@ data}]
```

and

```
Flatten@Thread@data
```

Comment: A.G thank you! but none of them work for what I want. None of them get `data` to be `{-7.10543`*^-15, -7.10543`*^-15, -9.03439`, -8.8538`, -10.0876`, -2.49194`,-2.98661`,-6.39488`*^-14, 2.8421699999999997`*^-14, 8.67852`, 2.85633`,11.1115`, 2.74509`, 13.5305`}, {3.29215`, 2.94365`, 2.4954`, 3.33308`, 3.1443`,2.00957`, 3.35066`, 3.29215`, 2.73316`, 2.05735`, 3.04537`, 2.49008`, 3.11135`,2.20002`}`

Comment: @John Can you please explain what output you want with input `{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Transpose[data]
```

should work. `Transpose` swaps rows and columns, so a list

```
{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}
```

becomes

```
{{a,c,e},{b,d,f}}
```

Your output then is a *list* of 2 lists, hence the outer set of parentheses. If you want the two separate you'll have to assign/output them separately:

```
transposed = Transpose[data]
data1 = transposed[[1]]
data2 = transposed[[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @AλέξανδροςΖεγγ says, you can use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten)'s 4th syntax:

```
data={
    {-7.10543*10^-15,3.29215},
    {-7.10543*10^-15,2.94365},
    {-9.03439,2.4954},
    {-8.8538,3.33308},
    {-10.0876,3.1443},
    {-2.49194,2.00957},
    {-2.98661,3.35066},
    {-6.39488*10^-14,3.29215},
    {2.84217*10^-14,2.73316},
    {8.67852,2.05735},
    {2.85633,3.04537},
    {11.1115,2.49008},
    {2.74509,3.11135},
    {13.5305,2.20002}
};

Flatten[data,{2,1}]
```

> {-7.10543*10^-15, -7.10543*10^-15, -9.03439, -8.8538, -10.0876, -2.49194, 
> -2.98661, -6.39488*10^-14,
> 2.84217*10^-14, 8.67852, 2.85633, 11.1115, 2.74509, 13.5305, 3.29215, 
> 2.94365, 2.4954, 3.33308, 3.1443, 2.00957, 3.35066, 3.29215, 2.73316, 
> 2.05735, 3.04537, 2.49008, 3.11135, 2.20002}

Comment: Yes, that's it. That `Flatten` actually has the functionality of transposition besides combining dimensions, maybe few people know it.